Transaction is not going through even when bundle receipt returns 1
I am trying to implement a swap feature in my app where users can swap tokens. It uses Uniswap's SwapRouterV2 to do the swap and it works perfectly. But now I am trying to implement Flashbot into it to make my transactions private so I created two transactions: approve transaction and swap transaction. Bundles them together as an array and calling sendBundle in FlashBotProvider. The transaction is not going through at all even though I get 1 as bundleReceipt. Please note that I'm using Sepolia testnet and Flashbot's Sepolia relay. This is the bundle response:
 {
  to: '0x3bFA4769FB09eefC5a80d6E87c3B9C650f7Ae48E',
  data: '0x04e45aaf000000000000000000000000fff9976782d46cc05630d1f6ebab18b2324d6b140000000000000000000000001c7d4b196cb0c7b01d743fbc6116a902379c72380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bb80000000000000000000000004808ff500c467244e91af2220fab83202094ccce000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016345785d8a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003a9cb9f80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
}
maxPriorityFeePerGas:  10142890n
bundleResponse:  {
  bundleTransactions: [
    {
      signedTransaction: '0x02f8b483aa36a781e6839ac4aa8504d599097e830927c094fff9976782d46cc05630d1f6ebab18b2324d6b1480b844095ea7b30000000000000000000000003bfa4769fb09eefc5a80d6e87c3b9c650f7ae48e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016345785d8a0000c001a06432e56f07c65cea7e446e8a741107c2d828b1de800776a95c7fda179945300fa04c459baac02562c9cca53d38a4e77f53949b91d4dc959ad62459c9590600f080',
      hash: '0xb8e5a45811aa2d4cbd7798b8fee96d780415a6c011709a9363bac0f846601fc4',
      account: '0x4808Ff500C467244e91af2220faB83202094CCCe',
      nonce: 230
    },
    {
      signedTransaction: '0x02f9015483aa36a781e7839ac4aa8504d599097e830927c0943bfa4769fb09eefc5a80d6e87c3b9c650f7ae48e80b8e404e45aaf000000000000000000000000fff9976782d46cc05630d1f6ebab18b2324d6b140000000000000000000000001c7d4b196cb0c7b01d743fbc6116a902379c72380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bb80000000000000000000000004808ff500c467244e91af2220fab83202094ccce000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016345785d8a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003a9cb9f80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c001a036ead584b135a53857866c6b59fb989db00603d999cd8278207b39099918a9f0a04f54ec55b2e3dfc4b422a7033e2e3c43973897a4d2db5f356bf27893c83a0a30',
      hash: '0x626b5a652ffe04e667b68b970043e0d80ca476e307102f648f459b25fcb8763a',
      account: '0x4808Ff500C467244e91af2220faB83202094CCCe',
      nonce: 231
    }
  ],
  wait: [Function: wait],
  simulate: [Function: simulate],
  receipts: [Function: receipts],
  bundleHash: '0x627495d609e8a0cc6d117162c17081e527595a6ff7100258fa657584ddbeb1e3'
}


If you check the hashes in EtherScan in Sepolia testnet, you will see that 404 not found is shown. I have tried sendPrivateTransaction as well. Also, I have signed the bundle with signBundle and then used sendBundle but that time I get Do not know how to serialize a BigInt. Also tried after increasing gasLimit and fee per gas and prioriy fee per gas. But nothing.
I am fairly new to this type of development and after a lot of struggle I could make swap transactions work with Uniswap's SDK (without flashbot) but with flashbot is it just not working. I really want to use Flashbot.
Here's a part of the code:
async swap(token, amount, type) {
    const flashBotProvider = await FlashbotsBundleProvider.create(
            this.providerService.provider, 
            this.walletService.wallet,     
            process.env.FLASHBOT_ENDPOINT,
            'sepolia'  
    );

    amount = convertAmount(token, amount, type);

    try {
        const approvalTransaction   = await this.approveTokenTransaction(WETH_TOKEN.address, TOKEN_IN_ABI, amount);;
        const { poolContract, fee } = await this.getPoolInfo(this.factoryContract, WETH_TOKEN, token);
        const quotedAmountOut       = await this.quoteAndLogSwap(this.quoterContract, fee, amount, token, type);
        const params                = await this.prepareSwapParams(poolContract, amount, quotedAmountOut, token, type);
        const swapRouter            = getContract(SWAP_ROUTER_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, SWAP_ROUTER_ABI, this.walletService.wallet);
        const swapTransaction       = await this.getSwapTransaction(swapRouter, params);
        const feeData               = await this.providerService.provider.getFeeData();
        const maxFeePerGas          = feeData.maxFeePerGas * 10n;
        const maxPriorityFeePerGas  = feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas * 10n;
        const bundle                = [
            {
                signer: this.walletService.wallet,
                transaction: {
                    ...approvalTransaction,
                    chainId: SEPOLIA_CHAIN_ID,
                    gasLimit: 600000n,
                    maxFeePerGas,
                    maxPriorityFeePerGas,
                },
            },
            {
                signer: this.walletService.wallet,
                transaction: {
                    ...swapTransaction,
                    chainId: SEPOLIA_CHAIN_ID,
                    gasLimit: 600000n,
                    maxFeePerGas,
                    maxPriorityFeePerGas,
                },
            }
        ];

        const blockNumber           = await this.providerService.provider.getBlockNumber();
        const bundleResponse        = await flashBotProvider.sendBundle(bundle, blockNumber + 1);
        const bundleReceipt         = await bundleResponse.wait();

        if (bundleReceipt === 1) {
            console.log(`Flashbots Bundle Confirmed! Approval + Swap executed`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Flashbots Bundle Not Included`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error.message);
    }
}

If you want to see more code, please let me know.

The problem might be due to the testnet because Flashbots relays on testnets are generally less stable compared to their mainnet counterparts.
You can try to simulate your bundle before actually sending it. This might provide additional details regarding the issue. By doing so, you can even test it on the mainnet without spending gas.

Hello. Thanks for your answer. I think my code is alright cause day before yesterday I submitted a bundle and I got 0 as bundle receipt response. After I checked the block I could see my transactions and after a while the transactions went through and swap occurred succesfully. But then I tried another bundle. This time I got 1 as receipt response, but my transaction was not included in the block and nothing happened. So I'm assuming something is wrong with testnet.

Yes exactly. You could also try simulating the sending of the transaction bundle on the mainnet, as it won’t consume any gas.

Can you explain me something? I just did a simulation and I got this error: Simulation Error: err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address <MY-ADDRESS> have 0.965 ETH want 1.756 ETH; txhash <SOME-HASH>. I have 0.965 ETH and 1.08254 WETH in my testnet wallet. I'm trying to swap 0.1 WETH for some USDC. How did it come up with such high (1.756 ETH) gas cost? Where did this value come from?

I think, it’s due to the 10n multiplier that you’re using for maxFeePerGas as well as maxPriorityFeePerGas. Can you try reducing the multiplier or just avoid multiplying completely?

Now I keep getting TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt.

Can you try multiplying with 1n instead of 10n?

Same. Please note that I hardcoded gasLimit to 600000n.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Flashbots in Sepolia have little block success rate
Sometimes below 10%
You have to wait up to 5 minutes sometimes before Flashbots validate the block and include your tx
You can see if block validated by Flashbots in Sepolia at the 'Extra Data' of block on Etherscan
For example here https://sepolia.etherscan.io/block/7101246 it always states 'Illuminate Dmocratize Dstribute'

Hi. Thank you for your message. But what does 'Illuminate Dmocratize Dstribute' mean? Do you think my code is alright? Do you think it will work fine in mainnet?

This is the name of validator running Flashbots in Ethereum Sepolia Testnet
